# EADDRINUSE error nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

so i wanted to setup a gambling site and wanted to check prices with nodejs, but this isnt really working.. can anybody help me?

everytime i try nodejs site this pops up:

```
root@localhost:/var/www/html/Bot/BOT# nodejs site
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.177] [TRACE] [default] - Strange error
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.179] [DEBUG] [default] - { [Error: listen EADDRINUSE] code: 'EADDRINUSE', errno: 'EADDRINUSE', syscall: 'listen' }
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:228:9)
    at new Server (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:52:17)
    at Server (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:40:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/site.js:3:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.195] [INFO] [default] - DB Connection ID: 184
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.197] [INFO] [default] - DB Connection ID: 185
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.197] [INFO] [default] - DB Connection ID: 186
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.198] [INFO] [default] - DB Connection ID: 187
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.199] [TRACE] [default] - Roll 1
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.200] [TRACE] [default] - Sucesfully updated history
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.200] [WARN] [default] - Loaded hash594b7214a8e846d02a0187421148940170d2fcf18199f81721c082ca84d93808
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.539] [WARN] [default] - Loaded fresh prices
[2017-05-04 14:50:45.548] [WARN] [default] - Prices loaded from cache
[2017-05-04 14:50:48.174] [TRACE] [default] - Strange error
[2017-05-04 14:50:48.174] [DEBUG] [default] - { [Error: listen EADDRINUSE] code: 'EADDRINUSE', errno: 'EADDRINUSE', syscall: 'listen' }
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:228:9)
    at null._onTimeout (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/site.js:618:29)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to access a port that is already in use?

Comment: Error: Address In Use.

Answer (score 0):

This means (without seeing your code) that the port your server is specified to listen on is already in use. You can either change the port, or make sure to quit any process that is using that port.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I know the problem. Which ports do I have to open?

Comment: You shouldn't have to open any port. Are you sure that you're not already running the server in another terminal? You can also change the port in the configuration.

Comment: I have only a few ports opened. So there are only 4 ports available. I can open more, but which ones?

Comment: I do not have another terminal opened.

Comment: A port not being open shouldn't cause that error. I'd recommend you restart the computer to ensure that no processes using that port are running. If there are still issues, then you should change the port for your server.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a possibility that you are not allowed to access a port because you do not have the permission to do so regardless of getting the error: EADDRINUSE.

Try running in admin mode with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me all the time when the process didn't get killed.  As long as you're not running any other node processes you need this command will make that error go away.  Type in terminal

```
killall node
```

Voila!

Comment: For Windows users: `tskill node`